# Java heap smaller than expected

Tags: java, memory

A primary project of mine was having some heap size issues which I fixed. I decided to experiment with the way I fixed it. I ran the following with `java -jar <jarfile> -Xmx5G -Xms4G`. (Initial 4GB, max 5GB).

```
int i = 0;

try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        sb.append('0');
    }
} catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
    System.out.println("At: " + i);
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which printed

```
At: 603979774
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
```

Why is my heap access limited to 2 bytes short of 576mb when It was set as at least 4gb?

Comment: Because a `char` is 2 bytes, not 1 byte, so it's not allocating 576 MB but twice that, and there might be memory fragmentation (no continuous block of memory of the requested size available). Also space is needed for the old as well as the new array when re-allocating.

Comment: But what about the bit where I give it 5gb? Also, my computer has 16gb and the windows uses 2.2gb passively, so there is likely enough space. Task manager also shows that there is little fragmentation in the memory as it is all at the start.

Comment: Have you checked for bitness? System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model") );

Comment: On top of the above, the JVM is crashing while is trying to copy the original array inside the StringBuilder to a bigger one. So memory is more than doubled at that point.

Comment: What size is your JVM in bits? 32? 64? What operating system are you running on? You are leaving out very important information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the other answers forgot an important point.

The code crashes when it tries to copy the original array inside `StringBuilder` to another array ([double the size from the original one](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/AbstractStringBuilder.java#AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity%28int%29)).

In this case

1. Size of the original array ~ 1.2GB
2. Size of the new array ~ 2.4GB

At this point the JVM won't be able to fit the new array on new generation memory pool and crashes.

Comment: Just to clarify, this final copy op required 4.8gb of memory while the JVM was allowed 5gb. This should work. Nope. JVM needs 200mb it seems. **This program does complete without error given 6gb of memory (4.8gb for itself & 1.2gb for JVM overhead.)**

Comment: It won't work... you're not taking the different memory pools into consideration. The arrays must fit completely in one of the memory pools. How java splits the memory pools depends on the version and command line flags. Probably the new generation pool has ~3.5GB if the jvm was given 5GB of ram.

Comment: Please, before you state that some code won't work, especially when it comes to runtime matters like memory, test it. It works for me perfectly fine. I think you'll find that it works fine for you if you give it 6gb.

Answer (score 1):

You are appending a UNICODE character which is 2 bytes. Your iterator, i, is 600M. Therefore you allocated approximately 1.2GB of memory.

On a 32 bit JVM the theoretical size you can allocate on the heap is 4GB. But that isn't likely because there are other factors that come into play (swap, kernel, fragmentation), the O/S you are running takes up memory, the JVM takes up memory, apps that are running take up memory, device drivers, services, etc. You don't get the entire 4GB of theoretical heap (2^32). If I remember, if you are running on 32 bit Windows with 32-bit JVM, the limit is somewhere around the 1.2GB mark.

Comment: Print out the capacity and length of the Stringbuilder in the catch block.